# converting gregorian date to hijri date using java/swing

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser, hijri

Does any one know the way to convert gregorian dates to hijri dates using Jdatechooser.
(java/swing) 
any help on the solution will be appreciated. 
thanks,

Comment: I don't know much about it, but you could take a look at Joda's [Islamic calendar](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_islamic.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at this source code, I think it is what you need.
http://code.google.com/p/hijricalendar/source/browse/trunk/HijriCalendar/src/HijriCalTest.java